# Python Mocking AWS Wrangler / DB Connection

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, aws-data-wrangler

I'm new to Python and testing and trying to write some tests that interact with AWS wrangler in my Python 3 lambda function.  [Here is the documentation](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.postgresql.connect.html).

The function I want to test looks like

```
def finalize_request(request_id: str):
    logging.info(f"Marking request: {request_id} as complete")

    try:
        with wr.postgresql.connect(DB_CONNECTION_NAME) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    f"UPDATE log.account_status_chart_request SET processed_date = NOW() WHERE request_id = '{request_id}'"
                )
                conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An exception occurred while finalizing the request: {e}")
        raise e
```

I've sucessfully intercepted the `wr.postgresql.connect` portion of the code using

```
def test_finalize_request(mocker):
    mock_connection = mocker.MagicMock()

    @contextmanager
    def mock_connect(*args, **kwargs):
        yield mock_connection

    finalize_request(request_id=1)
```

What I'm trying to do is within my `mock_connection` specifically grap the `cursor.execute` and override it.  I'm pushing in some dummy data to a `sqlite` database and want to do my update in that database.

Thoughts?

The expectation is that I have another function called `mock_update` or something of the likes that simply runs something like

```
connection.execute(
        <sql parameter extracted from the original cursor.execute>
    )
connection.commit()
```

I can then read the value to make sure the processed date is set.